# Crear una variable de conteo en Python

Tags: python

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]puede parecer una pregunta simple a primera vista pero, como soy nuevo en Python, no dimensiono bien como realizar esto.
Tengo una base de datos que generalmente se trabaja en Excel. Cada fila de la base está asociada a un determinado ID. En excel, para saber cuantos ID hay registrados por mes, solo tengo que agregar los meses en columnas y los ID como conteo. Pero en Python no sé como realizar esto.

No sé si me pudieran dar alguna idea para solucionar esto
Muchas gracias

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow! Si adjuntas lo que llevas intentado tu pregunta quedaria mucho mejor. Un saludo :)

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes la base de datos en Python? ¿Es una lista de diccionarios? ¿Una lista de tuplas? ¿Lo lees de la excel usando pandas? ¿Los IDs se repiten? Sin concretar más la pregunta no puede responderse. Estaría bien también que mostraras un ejemplo de la estructura de la tabla excel.

Comment: Gracias por responder, abulafia.
La base excel la leo desde panda, y los ID (caso_numero, según la base) no se repiten.
En la pregunta adjunté una vista de la base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si has leido la hoja excel a un dataframe llamado por ejemplo `df` y los nombres de las columnas del dataframe coinciden con los mostrados en tu captura de pantalla de la excel, entonces la siguiente línea te computará una tabla (`Series` pandas) en la que los índices son los diferentes números de mes, y los valores son el número (conteo) de IDs en cada mes:

```
df.groupby("mes_ingreso").caso_numero.count()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta, me sirvió mucho
Una ultima consulta:
Tengo este código
conteo_tipo=reclamos.groupby(['categoria_cti','tipo_cti'])['caso_numero'].count(), pero me salen los datos de forma desordenada, sabes como podría presentarlos de mayor a menor?

Muchas gracias!!

Comment: Supongo que te refieres a ordenar la columna de contadores, no los números del mes (que deberían salir ordenados). En ese caso simplemente añade al final de tu expresión `.sort_values(ascending=False)`